# When adding element to an array in PHP, last element is added twice

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having a weird problem where when I add elements to an array in PHP, the last element is added twice. For example, I create 3 arrays, but when I combine them using `array_push()` or `$array[]`, it duplicates the last element, giving me 4 arrays. Here's an example:

```
$master_array = [];
foreach($days as $i=>$day){
    $single_array[$i] = array(
        'id' => $day->id,
        'some_variable' => $day->some_variable
    );
    $master_array[] = $single_array[$i];
}
$result = json_encode($master_array);
```

If desired output is `[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]`, then it will echo `[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[3,4]`, duplicating the last element. Seems to be okay until I run the `json_encode`. Any suggestions?

Comment: As you're json_encoding $past_appts which isn't referenced anywhere else in the code snippet you're showing, it's anybody's guess why

Comment: Good catch, I just switched my variables to generic ones for simplicity, missed one. And days is referring to rows of a SQL query.

Comment: I don't know, what part of your code you are missing in the example - but you are "pushing" associative Arrays to "master_array". Since json does not know associative arrays, your result wouldn't be a list of arrays anyway, but a list of objects. So, it would be `[{"id":1, "somevalue":2},{"id":2, "somevalue":3},{"id":3, "somevalue":4}]` - and not what you are saying the output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing a multidimensional array for `$single_array`? You don't need the extra dimension.

```
$master_array = array();
foreach($days as $i=>$day){
    $single_array = array(
        'id' => $day->id,
        'some_variable' => $day->some_variable
    );
    $master_array[] = $single_array;
}
$result = json_encode($past_appts);
```

Comment: +1 cause you are right, but -1 because this does not change anything. He could also use `$singleArray[0][0][0][1]` - and if he accesses it the same way, he has the same issue.